# RxJava2/RxAndroid Fetching information from website issue

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to explore Rxjava 2 and get some issue with fetching information from website. Actutally Observer give me an error.

My code:

```
observable.subscribe(getObserver());
```

Observable

```
 Observable<String> observable = Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        String data = getHeadlines(SOURCE_WEB);
        return data;
    }
});
```

Observer

```
 protected <String> Observer<String> getObserver() {
    return new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            Log.i("Observer get: ", "mamy sub");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(String value) {
            Log.i("Observer get: ",value.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.i("Observer get ", "Error");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            Log.i("Observer  ", "complete");
        }
    };
}
```

My fetching method

```
    public String getHeadlines(String source) throws IOException {
    Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect(source).get();
    Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("h2");


    return newsHeadlines.toString();
}
```

When I'm using AsyncTask everything work fine...

Comment: exceptions? errors?

Comment: Observer call onError method, but I resolve my problem a long time ago. Just needed to and Schedulers.newThread() to Observable! thanks anyway